# Is there any convenient way to readline without the \n?

Tags: python, string, file, readline

I have a function named `read_proxy`, I want to read each line of the text:

```
def read_proxy():
    f = open('./proxy.txt', 'r')
    proxies = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return proxies

if __name__ == '__main__':

    proxies = read_proxy()
    print(proxies)  # ['a\n', 'sad\n', 'asdasd\n', 'asdas\n', '1223\n', '43\n', '4576\n', '789\n', '90900-\n']
```

You see list item, each have a `\n` at the end.
How to write the `read_proxy()`,  let me implement get the each line string not with the `\n`? In my option I only can forloop each item then strip the `\n` out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why Python decided to do this, but iterating over a file returns its lines.  So you can also write:

```
with open('./proxy.txt', 'r') as file:
    return [line.rstrip('\n') for line in file]
```

For very large files, this is probably more efficient that reading the entire file into memory, and then parsing it.  There is no need for two copies of the file (one with newlines, one without) in memory.

Comment: Re your last point, I would argue that if very large files might be used, then it may be necessary to refactor the calling code so that *zero* copies of the whole file exist in memory. You could then instead provide a generator function yielding one (stripped) line at a time, which the caller can iterate over.

Comment: I agree with you, and I probably shouldn't have brought up the efficiency point.  My main points should have been that (1) context managers simplify code  and (2) file handles are iterable objects.

I still think it's a nice clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
def read_proxy_without_newlines():
    f = open('./proxy.txt', 'r')
    proxies = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return [p.rstrip('\n') for p in proxies]
```

Comment: Do you mean can only get the items with `\n` then delete it? cannot do any thing magic in open() function?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.readlines()`, which reads each line separately into a list and keeps the `\n` at the end, you could try instead using `.read()` to get the entire file at once, and then use `str.split()` to turn it into a list of lines, but *removing* the newlines this time:

```
def read_proxy():
    f = open('./proxy.txt', 'r')
    proxies = f.read().split('\n')
    f.close()
    return proxies
```

Comment: Any reason you choose not to guard the file with a `with` expression?

Comment: @flakes Copying the OP's code as closely as possible, making only the modification necessary to demonstrate the solution. Of course using `with` is the proper way to do file I/O most of the time, including in this situation, but that's not what this question is asking.